# How to save checkbox values in a table?

Tags: fix-my-code, database

How can i insert data from a html form to a table in Joomla database.
**Sample code of the form**:
`Name : <input type="textbox" name="username">
Selection1 : <input type="checkbox" name="choice1" value="first">
Selection2 :<input type="checkbox" name="choice2" value="second">
Selection3: <input type="checkbox" name="choice3" value="third">
<input type="submit" value="submit" action="save_to_joomla_database.php"></form>`

What's the script i need to write in `save_to_joomla_database.php` which will store the data in any specific table of the Joomla database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will first need to get the values using JInput like so,

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$username = $input->get('username');
$choice1 = $input->get('choice1');
$choice2 = $input->get('choice2');
$choice3 = $input->get('choice3');
```

then for your database query, you can use the following:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo(); 
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$columns = array('username', 'choice1', 'choice2', 'choice2');
$values = array($db->quote($username), $db->quote($choice1), $db->quote($choice2), $db->quote($choice3));

$query->insert($db->quoteName('#__table_name'))
      ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
      ->values(implode(',', $values));

$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
```

You will of course need to make some changes to the database query to suits your needs but this will get you started off

Answer (score 6):

@Lodder is definitely correct, but there is another syntax for those who are interested. I prefer this syntax because it saves typing the field names as many times

```
$data = new stdClass;
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$data->username = $input->get('username');
$data->choice1 = $input->get('choice1');
$data->choice2 = $input->get('choice2');
$data->choice3 = $input->get('choice3');

$db = JFactory::getDbo(); 
$db->insertObject('#__table_name', $data);
```

As long as your object's properties match the column names exactly, you can just insert the object directly into the table using `insertObject`

Comment: +1 ... I've never actually used this method before so thanks for pointing it out as it looks much simpler.